# How to do instantiation and call a method in a mouthful in PHP?

Tags: php

I tried these two ways:

```
(new NewsForm())->getWidgetSchema();

{new NewsForm()}->getWidgetSchema();
```

With no luck...

Comment: I agree with Mitch C's answer - Your usage seems to indicate a static method might be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't an instanciation and a method call in one instruction... But a way to "cheat" is to create a function that returns an instance of the class you're working with -- and, then, call a method on that function which returns an object :

```
function my_function() {
    return new MyClass();
}
my_function()->myMethod();
```

And, in this kind of situation, there is a useful trick : names of classes and names of functions don't belong to the same namespace -- which means **you can have a class and a function that have the same name** : they won't conflict !

So, you can create a function which has the same name as your class, instanciates it, and returns that instance :

```
class MyClass {
    public function myMethod() {
        echo 'glop';
    }
}

function MyClass() {
    return new MyClass();
}

MyClass()->myMethod();
```

*(Yeah, the name of the function is not that pretty, in this example -- but you see the point ;-) )*

Comment: WOW,is it a bug or feature of PHP?

Comment: Definitly not a bug ; just a "fact" *(some might call that a feature, I suppose ^^ )*, I would say : class names and function names are not stored in the same data structure, in the internals of PHP, I suppose

Comment: A static factory method within the class would be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not allow you to do this. Try:

```
function giveback($class)
{
    return $class;
}

giveback(new NewsForm())->getWidgetSchema();
```

It is a rather weird quirk with the language.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a static method you can just do this:

```
NewsForm::getWidgetSchema();
```

Comment: The poster said in the comments that it's not a static method.

Comment: The comment that the method wasn't static came after I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

A better option in my opinion would be to use a `factory` method:

```
class factory_demo {
    public static function factory()
    {
        return new self;
    }
    public function getWidgetSchema()
    { }
}
```

then

```
factory_demo::factory()->getWidgetSchema()
```

Of course, you get all the benefits of the factory pattern as well. Unfortunately this only works if you have access to the code, and are willing to change it.